# Difference between triggerEvent and dispatch

Tags: plugin-events, system-plugin

What is the difference between:

```
$result = $app->triggerEvent('onMyEvent', [$context, &$table, $data]);
```

and this:

```
$app->getDispatcher()->dispatch('onMyEvent', AbstractEvent::create(
    'onMyEvent',
    [
        'extension'  => $context,
        'subject'   => $this,
        'data'   => $data,
    ]
));
```

Is `triggerEvent` just going obsolete in future Joomla ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main difference is that `triggerEvent()` returns an array composed of values returned by the event handlers (i.e. plugins). Meanwhile, dispatcher's `dispatch()` method returns the event itself. The idea is that each event should be a concrete class with concrete arguments, ways of modifying it and ways of getting the needed results. If you are using the generic event created by `Joomla\CMS\Event\AbstractEvent::createEvent()` you're not really taking the advantage of the new system.

Comment: OK. Can you tell me a file, where using the new system can be seen? I thought using the dispatcher is using the new system.

Comment: Joomla\Component\Media\Administrator\Model\ApiModel::getFile() dispatches a FetchMediaItemEvent, but most of the core files are just using Joomla\CMS\Event\AbstractEvent::createEvent()

Comment: Thanks. Thats why i used it to.